# How to check sequence date range in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

When trying to check date ranges it does not return values.Here st_date and end_date for usr_id = 1 is sequence so it should return only usr_id = 1 values and should not return usr_id = 3 since it is not sequence . If the date range is not in sequence, it should not return any value.

```
    CREATE TABLE #temp(st_date DATETIME,end_date DATETIME,usr_id INT)
INSERT  #temp VALUES('2007-03-01 00:00:00.000','2015-01-31 00:00:00.000',1),
('2015-02-01 00:00:00.000','2017-04-01 00:00:00.000',1),
('2007-03-01 00:00:00.000','2014-01-31 00:00:00.000',2),
('2007-03-01 00:00:00.000','2015-01-31 00:00:00.000',3),
('2015-03-02 00:00:00.000','2017-04-01 00:00:00.000',3)
DECLARE @st_dt DATETIME = '2015-02-01 00:00:00',@end_dt DATETIME = '2016-10-21 00:00:00'

SELECT * FROM #temp WHERE  @st_dt BETWEEN st_date AND end_date
AND @end_dt BETWEEN st_date AND end_date

DROP TABLE #temp
```

Comment: This is not really relevant to the question. But why do you use `datetime` as a data type when it seems that you are merely interested in `date`. Note, that this can potentially lead to a misinterpretation of the results because `2019-12-21 12:52:12` is obviously **not** between `2019-12-20` and `2019-12-21`. Just a thought.

Comment: Do you have answer for my question ?

Comment: The query will not return any record because of the second clause: all of the end_date fields are *before* @end_date

Answer (score 0):

Here is better logic to check overlapping date ranges:

```
SELECT *
FROM #temp
WHERE usr_id = 1 AND
      @st_dt < end_date AND
      @end_dt > st_date ;
```

Two ranges overlap when one starts before the second ends, and the first ends after the second starts.

Comment: Thanks Gordan! I need to check if the date range is not in sequence, it should not return any value.

Answer (score 0):

**[SqlFiddleDemo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/c67ea/4/0)**

```
DECLARE @st_dt DATETIME = '2015-02-01 00:00:00',
       @end_dt DATETIME = '2019-10-21 00:00:00';

SELECT * 
FROM temp 
WHERE usr_id = 1 
  AND st_date >= @st_dt AND  st_date <= @end_dt
  AND end_date >= @st_dt AND end_date <= @end_dt;
```